# Exim:Use specific smarthost for certain recipient domain only

Tags: smtp, exim, smarthost

I'm looking for solution for the case described below.

I've to send mail to some domains (hotmail, outlook) via smarthost, because of blocking my server's IP (Hetzner) on side of Microsoft.

Key point here is that I need to relay not specified sender to smarthost(it's desirable though), but one and only one recipient domain (hotmail.com) should relayed via external smarthost

Excerpt from example of exim config

```
send_via_gmail:
   driver = manualroute
   domains = ! +local_domains
   senders = user@example.tld
   transport = gmail_smtp
   route_list = "* smtp.gmail.com"
```

Solution is quite simple at a glance.

Just adding domain needed in `domains` config list.

That's enough or not? 
May be there is better way to go.

P.S. Hmm.. or `domains = ! +local_domains` refers to sender's domain not recipient's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `domains` contains the target domains to which the router should send messages, so replacing it with a domainlist consisting "outlook.com" and "hotmail.com" will make Exim route those messages via the smarthost.

As a side note, your config contains a `senders` parameter as well, so the router will decline if the sender is not `user@example.tld`, regardless of the target domain.